# How to Select the Domain and Mappings of a Structure for ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

To establish semantics of a formal language $L$, e.g., FOL, we need a structure $M = (A, m_c, m_r, m_f)$, where $A$ is a set of domain, $m_{c}$ is a mapping such that for any constant symbol $c$ of $L$, $m_{c}\left(c\right) \in A$, $m_{r}$ is a mapping such that for any relation symbol $r$ of arity $n$ of $L$, $m_{r}\left(r\right) \subseteq A^{n}$, and for any function symbol $f$ of arity $n$ of $L$, $m_{f}\left(f\right): A^{n} \to A$. I am wondering how to select $M$ for some statements in $L$ to be true.

I would like to use a case I recently read for example. The case is about [Skolem's Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-skolem/), although the thing asked here may have little to do with the case itself. We know that under ZFC, we have the following statement: There exist some set which is infinitely uncountable. Let's assume that $\operatorname{UI}\left(x\right)$ means $x$ is infinitely uncountable. Then we have $\exists x \operatorname{UI}\left(x\right)$. Let $M = (A, m_c, m_r, m_f)$ be a structure we want to test. Then $M \models \exists x \operatorname{UI}\left(x\right)$ if we can find some $a \in A$ such that for every assignment of variables $j$, $\left(M, j\frac{a}{x}\right) \models \operatorname{UI}\left(x\right)$ (I am assuming that people are familiar with notation $j\frac{a}{x}$). Then $\left(M, j\frac{a}{x}\right) \models \operatorname{UI}\left(x\right)$ means that $a \in f_{r}\left(\operatorname{UI}\right)$. It seems to me that $A$ and $f_{r}$ have to restricted in some way when selected so that there exists $a \in A$ and $a \in f_{r}\left(\operatorname{UI}\right)$. Then is there a way to establish the correspondence between a language and a structure to make its sentences true?

Comment: What does $f_r(UI)$ mean?

Comment: The set of n-tuples for UI.

Comment: Set theory only has one binary symbol $\in$, so there is no reason to consider $m_c$ and $m_f$ in your example.

Comment: @HanulJeon In my understanding, yes or no. Pure ZFC has no function symbol. But we can introduce extensions to reduce the number of quantifiers. For instance, power set, singleton of, empty set, etc. But you are right in that for pure ZFC, we do not need $m_{c}$ and $m_{f}$.